# How can I add default static values, as well as dynamic values in React useForm? TS type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this useForm:

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
    reset,
    getValues,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      celebUid, //props
      fanUid, // props
      price, // props
    },
  });
```

Now when I try to add a value dynamically through an input, I get this type error:

```
 {...register("requestAction", {
                required: "choose a request event",
              })}

//Argument of type '"requestAction"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"celebUid" | "fanUid" | "price"'.ts(2345)
```

I understand that I can get rid of the error by simply adding requestAction to my defaultValues with an empty string, but that doesn't feel appropriate, and I don't want to do it for all the values since it's quite a large form.

when I don't have my default values, this works fine, and I don't get the type error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this,

```html
type FormData = {
  staticValue: string;
  dynamicValue: string;
};


 // Define default static values
  const defaultValues: FormData = {
    staticValue: 'Default Static Value',
    dynamicValue: '',
  };

  // Create the form instance
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue, // Use setValue for dynamic values
    control,
  } = useForm<FormData>({
    defaultValues,
  });
```